# WPF - Is it possible to have a curved input box?

Tags: wpf, path, geometry

I want a textbox where you can input text from keyboard but be shown as an arc. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30090/Text-On-A-Path-in-WPF) in codeproject. Author created TextOnAPath control which can display curved text.

Source code:

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TextOnAPath : Control
{
    static TextOnAPath()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextOnAPath), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextOnAPath)));

        Control.FontSizeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextOnAPath),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFontPropertyChanged)));

        Control.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextOnAPath),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFontPropertyChanged)));

        Control.FontStretchProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextOnAPath),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFontPropertyChanged)));

        Control.FontStyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextOnAPath),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFontPropertyChanged)));

        Control.FontWeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextOnAPath),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFontPropertyChanged)));
    }

    static void OnFontPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextOnAPath textOnAPath = d as TextOnAPath;

        if (textOnAPath == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue == null || e.NewValue == e.OldValue)
            return;

        textOnAPath.UpdateText();
        textOnAPath.Update();
    }

    double[] _segmentLengths;
    TextBlock[] _textBlocks;

    Panel _layoutPanel;
    bool _layoutHasValidSize = false;

    #region Text DP
    public String Text
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(TextOnAPath),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnStringPropertyChanged),
            new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceTextValue)));

    static void OnStringPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextOnAPath textOnAPath = d as TextOnAPath;

        if (textOnAPath == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue || e.NewValue == null)
        {
            if (textOnAPath._layoutPanel != null)
                textOnAPath._layoutPanel.Children.Clear();
            return;
        }

        textOnAPath.UpdateText();
        textOnAPath.Update();
    }

    static object CoerceTextValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        if ((String)baseValue == "")
            return null;

        return baseValue;
    }

    #endregion

    #region TextPath DP
    public Geometry TextPath
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(TextPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextPathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextPath", typeof(Geometry), typeof(TextOnAPath),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,

                                      new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextPathPropertyChanged)));

    static void OnTextPathPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextOnAPath textOnAPath = d as TextOnAPath;

        if (textOnAPath == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue || e.NewValue == null)
            return;

        textOnAPath.TextPath.Transform = null;

        textOnAPath.UpdateSize();
        textOnAPath.Update();
    }

    #endregion

    #region DrawPath DP

    /// <summary>
    /// Set this property to True to display the TextPath geometry in the control
    /// </summary>
    public bool DrawPath
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(DrawPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DrawPathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DrawPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DrawPath", typeof(bool), typeof(TextOnAPath),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDrawPathPropertyChanged)));

    static void OnDrawPathPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextOnAPath textOnAPath = d as TextOnAPath;

        if (textOnAPath == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue || e.NewValue == null)
            return;

        textOnAPath.Update();
    }

    #endregion

    #region DrawLinePath DP
    /// <summary>
    /// Set this property to True to display the line segments under the text (flattened path)
    /// </summary>
    public bool DrawLinePath
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(DrawLinePathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DrawLinePathProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DrawFlattendPath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DrawLinePathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DrawLinePath", typeof(bool), typeof(TextOnAPath),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDrawLinePathPropertyChanged)));

    static void OnDrawLinePathPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextOnAPath textOnAPath = d as TextOnAPath;

        if (textOnAPath == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue || e.NewValue == null)
            return;

        textOnAPath.Update();
    }

    #endregion

    #region ScaleTextPath DP
    /// <summary>
    /// If set to True (default) then the geometry defined by TextPath automatically gets scaled to fit the width/height of the control
    /// </summary>
    public bool ScaleTextPath
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ScaleTextPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScaleTextPathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleTextPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleTextPath", typeof(bool), typeof(TextOnAPath),
                new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnScaleTextPathPropertyChanged)));

    static void OnScaleTextPathPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextOnAPath textOnAPath = d as TextOnAPath;

        if (textOnAPath == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue)
            return;

        bool value = (Boolean)e.NewValue;

        if (value == false && textOnAPath.TextPath != null)
            textOnAPath.TextPath.Transform = null;

        textOnAPath.UpdateSize();
        textOnAPath.Update();

    }

    #endregion

    void UpdateText()
    {
        if (Text == null || FontFamily == null || FontWeight == null || FontStyle == null)
            return;

        _textBlocks = new TextBlock[Text.Length];
        _segmentLengths = new double[Text.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
        {
            TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
            t.FontSize = this.FontSize;
            t.FontFamily = this.FontFamily;
            t.FontStretch = this.FontStretch;
            t.FontWeight = this.FontWeight;
            t.FontStyle = this.FontStyle;
            t.Text = new String(Text[i], 1);
            t.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);

            t.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

            _textBlocks[i] = t;
            _segmentLengths[i] = t.DesiredSize.Width;


        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Text == null || TextPath == null || _layoutPanel == null || !_layoutHasValidSize)
            return;

        List<Point> intersectionPoints;

        intersectionPoints = GeometryHelper.GetIntersectionPoints(TextPath.GetFlattenedPathGeometry(), _segmentLengths);

        _layoutPanel.Children.Clear();

        _layoutPanel.Margin = new Thickness(FontSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < intersectionPoints.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            double oppositeLen = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(intersectionPoints[i].X + _segmentLengths[i] - intersectionPoints[i + 1].X, 2.0) + Math.Pow(intersectionPoints[i].Y - intersectionPoints[i + 1].Y, 2.0)) / 2.0;
            double hypLen = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(intersectionPoints[i].X - intersectionPoints[i + 1].X, 2.0) + Math.Pow(intersectionPoints[i].Y - intersectionPoints[i + 1].Y, 2.0));

            double ratio = oppositeLen / hypLen;

            if (ratio > 1.0)
                ratio = 1.0;
            else if (ratio < -1.0)
                ratio = -1.0;

            //double angle = 0.0;

            double angle = 2.0 * Math.Asin(ratio) * 180.0 / Math.PI;

            // adjust sign on angle
            if ((intersectionPoints[i].X + _segmentLengths[i]) > intersectionPoints[i].X)
            {
                if (intersectionPoints[i + 1].Y < intersectionPoints[i].Y)
                    angle = -angle;
            }
            else
            {
                if (intersectionPoints[i + 1].Y > intersectionPoints[i].Y)
                    angle = -angle;
            }

            TextBlock currTextBlock = _textBlocks[i];

            RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform(angle);
            TranslateTransform translate = new TranslateTransform(intersectionPoints[i].X, intersectionPoints[i].Y - currTextBlock.DesiredSize.Height);
            TransformGroup transformGrp = new TransformGroup();
            transformGrp.Children.Add(rotate);
            transformGrp.Children.Add(translate);
            currTextBlock.RenderTransform = transformGrp;

            _layoutPanel.Children.Add(currTextBlock);

            if (DrawLinePath == true)
            {
                Line line = new Line();
                line.X1 = intersectionPoints[i].X;
                line.Y1 = intersectionPoints[i].Y;
                line.X2 = intersectionPoints[i + 1].X;
                line.Y2 = intersectionPoints[i + 1].Y;
                line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                _layoutPanel.Children.Add(line);
            }
        }

        // don't draw path if already drawing line path
        if (DrawPath == true && DrawLinePath == false)
        {
            Path path = new Path();
            path.Data = TextPath;
            path.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            _layoutPanel.Children.Add(path);
        }
    }

    public TextOnAPath()
    {
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _layoutPanel = GetTemplateChild("LayoutPanel") as Panel;
        if (_layoutPanel == null)
            throw new Exception("Could not find template part: LayoutPanel");

        _layoutPanel.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(_layoutPanel_SizeChanged);
    }

    Size _newSize;

    void _layoutPanel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _newSize = e.NewSize;

        UpdateSize();
        Update();
    }

    void UpdateSize()
    {
        if (_newSize == null || TextPath == null)
            return;

        _layoutHasValidSize = true;

        double xScale = _newSize.Width / TextPath.Bounds.Width;
        double yScale = _newSize.Height / TextPath.Bounds.Height;

        if (TextPath.Bounds.Width <= 0)
            xScale = 1.0;

        if (TextPath.Bounds.Height <= 0)
            xScale = 1.0;

        if (xScale <= 0 || yScale <= 0)
            return;

        if (TextPath.Transform is TransformGroup)
        {
            TransformGroup grp = TextPath.Transform as TransformGroup;
            if (grp.Children[0] is ScaleTransform && grp.Children[1] is TranslateTransform)
            {
                if (ScaleTextPath)
                {
                    ScaleTransform scale = grp.Children[0] as ScaleTransform;
                    scale.ScaleX *= xScale;
                    scale.ScaleY *= yScale;
                }

                TranslateTransform translate = grp.Children[1] as TranslateTransform;
                translate.X += -TextPath.Bounds.X;
                translate.Y += -TextPath.Bounds.Y;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ScaleTransform scale;
            TranslateTransform translate;

            if (ScaleTextPath)
            {
                scale = new ScaleTransform(xScale, yScale);
                translate = new TranslateTransform(-TextPath.Bounds.X * xScale, -TextPath.Bounds.Y * yScale);
            }
            else
            {
                scale = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0);
                translate = new TranslateTransform(-TextPath.Bounds.X, -TextPath.Bounds.Y );
            }

            TransformGroup grp = new TransformGroup();
            grp.Children.Add(scale);
            grp.Children.Add(translate);
            TextPath.Transform = grp;
        }
    }
}

public static class GeometryHelper
{
    public static List<Point> GetIntersectionPoints(PathGeometry FlattenedPath, double[] SegmentLengths)
    {
        List<Point> intersectionPoints = new List<Point>();

        List<Point> pointsOnFlattenedPath = GetPointsOnFlattenedPath(FlattenedPath);

        if (pointsOnFlattenedPath == null || pointsOnFlattenedPath.Count < 2)
            return intersectionPoints;

        Point currPoint = pointsOnFlattenedPath[0];
        intersectionPoints.Add(currPoint);

        // find point on flattened path that is segment length away from current point

        int flattedPathIndex = 0;

        int segmentIndex = 1;

        while (flattedPathIndex < pointsOnFlattenedPath.Count - 1 &&
            segmentIndex < SegmentLengths.Length + 1)
        {
            Point? intersectionPoint = GetIntersectionOfSegmentAndCircle(
                pointsOnFlattenedPath[flattedPathIndex],
                pointsOnFlattenedPath[flattedPathIndex + 1], currPoint, SegmentLengths[segmentIndex - 1]);

            if (intersectionPoint == null)
                flattedPathIndex++;
            else
            {
                intersectionPoints.Add((Point)intersectionPoint);
                currPoint = (Point)intersectionPoint;
                pointsOnFlattenedPath[flattedPathIndex] = currPoint;
                segmentIndex++;
            }
        }

        return intersectionPoints;
    }

    static List<Point> GetPointsOnFlattenedPath(PathGeometry FlattenedPath)
    {
        List<Point> flattenedPathPoints = new List<Point>();

        // for flattened geometry there should be just one PathFigure in the Figures
        if (FlattenedPath.Figures.Count != 1)
            return null;

        PathFigure pathFigure = FlattenedPath.Figures[0];

        flattenedPathPoints.Add(pathFigure.StartPoint);

        // SegmentsCollection should contain PolyLineSegment and LineSegment
        foreach (PathSegment pathSegment in pathFigure.Segments)
        {
            if (pathSegment is PolyLineSegment)
            {
                PolyLineSegment seg = pathSegment as PolyLineSegment;

                foreach (Point point in seg.Points)
                    flattenedPathPoints.Add(point);
            }
            else if (pathSegment is LineSegment)
            {
                LineSegment seg = pathSegment as LineSegment;

                flattenedPathPoints.Add(seg.Point);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("GetIntersectionPoint - unexpected path segment type: " + pathSegment.ToString());

        }

        return (flattenedPathPoints);
    }

    static Point? GetIntersectionOfSegmentAndCircle(Point SegmentPoint1, Point SegmentPoint2,
        Point CircleCenter, double CircleRadius)
    {
        // linear equation for segment: y = mx + b
        double slope = (SegmentPoint2.Y - SegmentPoint1.Y) / (SegmentPoint2.X - SegmentPoint1.X);
        double intercept = SegmentPoint1.Y - (slope * SegmentPoint1.X);

        // special case when segment is vertically oriented
        if (double.IsInfinity(slope))
        {
            double root = Math.Pow(CircleRadius, 2.0) - Math.Pow(SegmentPoint1.X - CircleCenter.X, 2.0);

            if (root < 0)
                return null;

            // soln 1
            double SolnX1 = SegmentPoint1.X;
            double SolnY1 = CircleCenter.Y - Math.Sqrt(root);
            Point Soln1 = new Point(SolnX1, SolnY1);

            // have valid result if point is between two segment points
            if (IsBetween(SolnX1, SegmentPoint1.X, SegmentPoint2.X) &&
                IsBetween(SolnY1, SegmentPoint1.Y, SegmentPoint2.Y))
            //if (ValidSoln(Soln1, SegmentPoint1, SegmentPoint2, CircleCenter))
            {
                // found solution
                return (Soln1);
            }

            // soln 2
            double SolnX2 = SegmentPoint1.X;
            double SolnY2 = CircleCenter.Y + Math.Sqrt(root);
            Point Soln2 = new Point(SolnX2, SolnY2);

            // have valid result if point is between two segment points
            if (IsBetween(SolnX2, SegmentPoint1.X, SegmentPoint2.X) &&
                IsBetween(SolnY2, SegmentPoint1.Y, SegmentPoint2.Y))
            //if (ValidSoln(Soln2, SegmentPoint1, SegmentPoint2, CircleCenter))
            {
                // found solution
                return (Soln2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // use soln to quadradratic equation to solve intersection of segment and circle:
            // x = (-b +/ sqrt(b^2-4ac))/(2a)
            double a = 1 + Math.Pow(slope, 2.0);
            double b = (-2 * CircleCenter.X) + (2 * (intercept - CircleCenter.Y) * slope);
            double c = Math.Pow(CircleCenter.X, 2.0) + Math.Pow(intercept - CircleCenter.Y, 2.0) - Math.Pow(CircleRadius, 2.0);

            // check for no solutions, is sqrt negative?
            double root = Math.Pow(b, 2.0) - (4 * a * c);

            if (root < 0)
                return null;

            // we might have two solns...

            // soln 1
            double SolnX1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(root)) / (2 * a);
            double SolnY1 = slope * SolnX1 + intercept;
            Point Soln1 = new Point(SolnX1, SolnY1);

            // have valid result if point is between two segment points
            if (IsBetween(SolnX1, SegmentPoint1.X, SegmentPoint2.X) &&
                IsBetween(SolnY1, SegmentPoint1.Y, SegmentPoint2.Y))
            //if (ValidSoln(Soln1, SegmentPoint1, SegmentPoint2, CircleCenter))
            {
                // found solution
                return (Soln1);
            }

            // soln 2
            double SolnX2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(root)) / (2 * a);
            double SolnY2 = slope * SolnX2 + intercept;
            Point Soln2 = new Point(SolnX2, SolnY2);

            // have valid result if point is between two segment points
            if (IsBetween(SolnX2, SegmentPoint1.X, SegmentPoint2.X) &&
                IsBetween(SolnY2, SegmentPoint1.Y, SegmentPoint2.Y))
            //if (ValidSoln(Soln2, SegmentPoint1, SegmentPoint2, CircleCenter))
            {
                // found solution
                return (Soln2);
            }
        }

        // shouldn't get here...but in case
        return null;
    }

    static bool IsBetween(double X, double X1, double X2)
    {
        if (X1 >= X2 && X <= X1 && X >= X2)
            return true;

        if (X1 <= X2 && X >= X1 && X <= X2)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextOnAPath:TextOnAPath FontSize="30" DrawPath="True" 
    Text="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy hen.">
        <TextOnAPath:TextOnAPath.TextPath>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0 C120,361 230.5,276.5 230.5,276.5 
                  L308.5,237.50001 C308.5,237.50001 419.5,179.5002 367.5,265.49993 
                  315.5,351.49966 238.50028,399.49924 238.50028,399.49924 L61.500017,
                  420.49911"/>
        </TextOnAPath:TextOnAPath.TextPath>
    </TextOnAPath:TextOnAPath>
</Grid>
```